# How to remove not connected data in collections (mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections: **articles** and **comments**. all **comments** have `article`_id. There are some **articles** were removed, but **comments** still exist.

Please help to to write `db.collection.remove()` request to remove all records in **comments** collection which have `article_id` of a nonexistent article?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
db.comments.remove({ _id: { $nin : db.articles.runCommand({distinct: "distinct", key: "_id"}).values}})
```